# Prove that $(a+1)^{b}>(b+1)^{a}$

Tags: inequality, monotone-functions

> For all $a$ and $b$ such that $a > b > 0$, prove that
>
> $$(a+1)^{b}>(b+1)^{a}.$$

It is equal to $\sqrt[a]{a+1} > \sqrt[b]{b+1}$, but the function $f(x) = \sqrt[x]{x+1}$ is decreasing for $x \in \left(0,+\infty\right)$ (actually it decreases on its entire domain), so doesn't it imply that $f(x_0) < f(x_1)$ is true, for all $x_0$ and $x_1$ in the domain where $x_0 > x_1$?

Is that sufficient to prove that the statement is false, or am I totally wrong?

Comment: $(3+1)^2 > (2+1)^3$ is sufficient to prove that the statement is false

Answer (score 2):

As you said, since $f(x)=\sqrt[x]{x+1}$ is decreasing for positive $x$, for $a>b>0$, we can write
$$\sqrt[b]{b+1} > \sqrt[a]{a+1}.$$
Raising each side to the $ab$th power will preserve the inequality and give
$$(b+1)^a > (a+1)^b.$$
This makes me believe the inequality is supposed to be reversed. Alternatively, it is intended that $b>a>0$ instead of $a>b>0$.

Comment: Nope. The inequality is wrong in both directions. $(1+2)^{1} < (1+1)^2$ but $(1+2)^4>(1+4)^2$.

Comment: You aren't accounting for $a>b$ Clement C.

Comment: @ClementC. Take the assumption as $a>b$ and use the second line in my answer. Then in the fist example you give, we have $b=1$, $a=2$, so then we should have $$(b+1)^a=(1+1)^2>(2+1)^1=(a+1)^b.$$
In the second example, $b=2$ and $a=4$ so we have
$$(b+1)^a=(2+1)^4 > (4+1)^2=(a+1)^b.$$
It checks out.

Comment: My bad. Missing assumptions, stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is reversed. If we consider the function $f(x)=\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$, we have:
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{t+1} $$ 
and since $g(t)=\frac{1}{t+1}$ is a decreasing function over $\mathbb{R}^+$, so it is $f(x)$. It follows that $a>b>0$ implies $f(a)<f(b)$ or $(a+1)^b\color{red}{<}(b+1)^a.$

Answer (score 1):

The inequality does not always hold. When $a = 2, b= 0.5$, then the [inequality fails](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2B2)%5E0.5%20-%20(1%2B0.5)%5E2).

Comment: even simplier, if a=2, b=1 it also fails

Answer (score 0):

Let us prove that for $0<b<a$ holds $$\frac{\ln{(a+1)}}{a}<\frac{\ln{(b+1)}}{b},$$ which is equivalent with $$(a+1)^b<(b+1)^a.$$

Firstly, observe that $$f(t)=\ln{(t+1)}-\frac{t}{t+1}\geq 0$$ for $t\geq 0$.

(Function $f(t)$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$, since $f'(t)=\frac{t}{(t+1)^2}\geq 0$. Therefore, for every $t\geq 0$ is $f(t)\geq f(0)=0$).

Define $$g(t)=\frac{\ln{(t+1)}}{t}$$ for $t\geq 0$.

Since $g'(t)=-\frac{f(t)}{t^2}\leq 0$ for $t\geq 0$, we can conclude that function $g$ is decreasing on $[0,\infty)$.

Therefore, for $0<b<a$ holds $g(b)>g(a)$, which is equivalent with $$\frac{\ln{(a+1)}}{a}<\frac{\ln{(b+1)}}{b}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I disproved it to myself by plotting the following graph;

$$y= (a+1)^b - (b+1)^a$$

where $a=nb$ and $n>1$;

$$y= (nb+1)^b - (b+1)^{nb}$$

now arbitrarily say $n=2$;

$$y= (2b+1)^b - (b+1)^{2b}$$

From a plotted graph, if $b=0.5$ then $a=1$ and then $y$ is a negative number.